# Full width floatingactionbutton in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I implement a full width floatingactionbutton without using padding in bottom of the screen in flutter

Comment: please add more information for example code and what exactly you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a different approach. You can implement the same using stack.

```
Stack(
children: <Widget>[
        Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 55,
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {

          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          icon: Icon( Icons.add),
          label: Text(
            'ADD',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
        ),
      ),
    )
]
)
```