# Make Extended FAB(FloatingActionButton) fluid-width with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, material-design

Is there a way to make an Extended FAB fluid-width like described in the Material 3 specification with flutter?

Try with a fitted box:

```
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: FittedBox(
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () {},
            label: const Text('My button'),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The result, the button has a height proportional to width, so the button becomes huge:

[image]

Try to restrict height:

```
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.red,
      height: 88,
      child: FittedBox(
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            onPressed: () {},
            label: const Text('My button'),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Result: the button is resized and doesn't take all space in the red container:

[image]

How to make it like this?: ([A fluid-width container is defined by its relationship to the dimensions of the screen, such as screen width or layout grid.](https://m3.material.io/components/extended-fab/guidelines#0aa975bb-4aec-4477-b5c3-6f63e392f837))
[image]

#### Related topics

- [flutter - How to change the size of FloatingActionButton? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786652/how-to-change-the-size-of-floatingactionbutton)
- [Full width floatingactionbutton in flutter? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072694/full-width-floatingactionbutton-in-flutter)
- [user interface - How to set size to FloatingActionButton - Flutter - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65552394/how-to-set-size-to-floatingactionbutton-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove FittedBox as below code, It will work

```
return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {},
        label: const Text('My button'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    ),
```